# If $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb R^3$, under what condition do we have $(a,b,c)\in f(\mathbb R^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say that $f(x,y) = (x+y, 3x-y,2x+y)$.

If $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb R^3$, under what condition do we have $(a,b,c)\in f(\mathbb R^3)$

How would I solve this *without* using matrices, and only linear systems? I don't really understand how to go about it. What exactly do we want to show?

if  $(a,b,c)\in f(\mathbb R^3)$ then $(a,b,c)\in (x+y, 3x-y,2x+y)$. I don't really know where to go from there? Should I be finding the solutions to $(a,b,c) = (x+y, 3x-y,2x+y)$? Wouldn't this be the equivalent of finding the inverse function? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $f(\mathbb{R}^3) = \{(a,b,c) : \exists (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ such that } a = x+y, b = 3x-y, c = 2x+y\}$.  So you don't say "$(a,b,c) \in (x+y,  3x-y, 2x+y)$"; you say "$(a,b,c) \in \{(a,b,c) : \exists (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ such that } a = x+y, b = 3x-y, c = 2x+y\}$.  (The thing on the right of "$\in$" has to be a set, not a vector containing expressions containing variables.)

Comment: @EricTowers Ah, you're right. Thanks for your reply. That does help clarify, but where do I go from there? Am I trying to define x and y as a function of a, b, and c? I tried to do this through linear systems and failed.

Comment: Why in the world do you want to avoid matrices?

Comment: @UmbertoP. At the time that this question was given to us, they expected us to solve it without them; I'd like to know how to do that.

Comment: If you can solve it *with* matrices, you should be able to reverse engineer the steps to solve it with linear equations.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I unfortunately cannot solve it with either, so I'm trying to build my knowledge back up from the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a system of equations
$$ \begin{array}{llll} x &+ & y &= a \\ 3x &- &y &= b \\ 2x &+ & y &= c \end{array}$$

Now row reduce:

$$ \begin{array}{llll} x &+ & y &= a \\  &- &4y &= b - 3a  \\  &- & y &= c - 2a \end{array}$$

$$ \begin{array}{llll} x &+ & y &= a \\  &  &y &= -c + 2a  \\  & & 4y &= -b +3a \end{array}$$

$$ \begin{array}{llll} x &+ & y &= a \\  &  &y &= -c + 2a  \\  & & 0 &= -5a -b + 4c \end{array}$$

This system is consistent if and only if $-5a - b + 4c = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much; this clears things up totally.

Answer (score 1):

$a+b=(x+y)+(3x-y)=4x$ $\implies$ $\displaystyle x=\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{4}$.

$a=x+y$ and $\displaystyle x=\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{4}$ $\implies$ $\displaystyle y=a-\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{4}=\frac{3a}{4}-\frac{b}{4}$.

But we need $2x+y=c$. So,

$$2\left(\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{4}\right)+\frac{3a}{4}-\frac{b}{4}=c$$

i.e., $5a+b-4c=0$.